# How do I assign a dictionary value to a variable?

Tags: python

I'm working on character stats for a battle system and I want to input the damage by having the system multiply one of the stats by `0.5`, but it doesn't accept the stat name as a reference because it's in a dictionary.

Can someone tell me how to fix this?

```
Mage = { 'name' : 'Mage',
         'lvl' : 0,
         'xp' : 0,
         'lvlNext' : 25,
         'stats' : {'PStrength' : 5,
                    'PProsperity' : 5,
                    'PDexterity' : 15,
                    'PVitality' : 5,
                    'PAgility' : 10,
                    'HP' : 30}}

PDMG = PStrength * .50
```

gives

```
NameError: name 'PStrength' is not defined
```

Comment: Well what did you expect `PStrength` to be? That's neither an identifier nor in scope, so was inevitably going to be a `NameError`. Please go and read https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

What you have to do to get the damage is :

```
Mage = { 'name' : 'Mage',
         'lvl' : 0,
         'xp' : 0,
         'lvlNext' : 25,
         'stats' : {'PStrength' : 5,
                    'PProsperity' : 5,
                    'PDexterity' : 15,
                    'PVitality' : 5,
                    'PAgility' : 10,
                    'HP' : 30}}

PDMG = Mage['stats']['PStrength'] * 0.50
```